# Mapping a selection option to a number in a hidden cell

Tags: excel

I created a dropdown menu in an Excel spreadsheet.

The user can choose between "Apple", "Orange", or "Banana". I am trying to come up with a solution where when the user selects a choice, a number gets added to a hidden cell.

So let's say when option "Apple" is chosen, a hidden cell should have the value 5, when "Orange" is selected, it should be 78, and when "Banana" is selected, the number is 714.

Can this be done in Excel?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it with just a formula... `=IF(A1="Banana",714,IF(A1="Apple",5,IF(A1="Orange",78,"")))` This one is considering that the dropdown list is on cell A1. Just custom it...

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming the drop-down is located in cell A1:

**If you have few values:**

```
=if(A1="Apple";5;if(A1="Orange";78;if(A1="Banana";714;"No Fruit")))
```

**If you have many values:**

Create a table with Fruits in column 1 and the given number in column 2, name it e.g. "Fruit_Table"

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;Fruit_Table;2;FALSE)
```